# Show custom message/info for authors in add/edit post page

Tags: customization

I have a multi author blog and i need show a global info message in top of add post page, so all authors can read it when they come in this specific page, how i can add it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

i solved with this code placed in functions.php

```
function my_admin_notice(){
echo '<div class="updated">
<p>message here!</p>
</div>';
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
```

Comment: That will display the notice everywhere on wp-admin pages if I'm not mistaken. :)

Comment: Yes its worked good for me, thank you for your help!

Comment: This worked for me in 2023! I modified it slightly with `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_SERVER); echo "</pre>"` in place of the _message_ to print all server variables, but only in admin area at top.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by hooking into the `edit-post.php` page. There are a variety of hooks you could use, for example, if you want to display a message below the edit title field, you could hook into `edit_form_after_title`.

See the example code I have below with comments:

```
add_action(
  'edit_form_after_title', // the hook
  'wpse_228208' // the function
);

function wpse_228208() {

  global $post;

  // confirm if the post_type is 'post'
  if ($post->post_type!== 'post')
    return;

  // you can also perform a condition for post_status, for example, if you don't want to display the message if post is already published:
  if ($post->post_status!== 'publish')
    return;

   // here goes your message
   echo '<div style="">Hello world!</div>';
}
```

Comment: where is edit-post.php?

Comment: I was referring to the add/edit post page you're targeting. Try placing this code in your `functions.php` file to see it in effect.

Comment: ok i add it in functions.php but Hello Word text did'nt show..thank you for all help

Comment: Ok when i add you code, results is an error 500

Comment: Are you sure that you have added it correctly? It should work, there are no errors in the code that I've posted. What exact error are you receiving? 500 error is not related to the code I've provided you. :)

Comment: yes it's really strange...

Comment: Do you get this error when you remove this code from `functions.php?

Comment: no error, maybe it's a theme issue

Answer (score 0):

To show it above the title you can do this.

Add the following to your functions.php and make a js file of the same name in your theme directory.

```
function admin_js_custom() {
    $adminjs = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin-js.js';
    echo '"<script type="text/javascript" src="'. $adminjs . '"></script>"';
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'admin_js_custom');
```

And then place this code in the js file.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var message = "Message for the authors.";
    $('<p>' + message + '</p>').insertBefore('#titlediv')
});
```

Comment: It did work for me though. http://prntscr.com/ba4x6o Try replacing the javascript by this http://pastebin.com/n4xvNTww

Comment: Why use javascript when you can output the text via PHP?

Comment: Simple because the OP wanted it on "top" of the page. Your approach will also work, so given another approach to the OP in case he likes it above the title? Nothing wrong with that eh ?

Comment: i try but show nothing Thanks anyway

Comment: why dont show nothing....

Comment: probably coz you are doing something wrong. are you sure you named the javascript file as admin-js.js and put it in the wp-content/themes/themename/ directory?